# How to get AccountId from compressed public key in an ink! contract?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I'm trying to do the signature verification in an ink! contract. I'm using [ink_env::ecdsa_recover](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/crates/env/src/api.rs#L493) for this purpose.

It is returning Compressed Public Key of type `[u8; 33]`.
I have the AccountId of the signer in the contract storage.

Is there a way I can get the AccountId from the Compressed Public Key to verify the signer? or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A compressed public key can be represented by the `ECDSAPublicKey` struct from the `eth_compatibility` [crate](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/crates/eth_compatibility) from ink.

Try to create an `ECDSAPublicKey` struct from your uncompressed public key and then invoke the `to_default_account_id()` function from it which is defined [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/crates/eth_compatibility/src/lib.rs#L140-L150).

Try the following:

1. Add the `eth_compatibility` crate to your project
2. Import `eth_compatibility::ECDSAPublicKey`
3. Define an `ecdsa_key` from your `compressed_pub_key` with: `let ecdsa_key=ECDSAPublicKey::from(compressed_pub_key);`
4. Derive an `account_id` of type `AccountId` with: `let account_id=ecdsa_key.to_default_account_id();`

Comment: `AccountId::from()` takes in `[u8; 32]`. Since `ink_env::ecdsa_recover` returns `[u8; 33]`, it is throwing an error. My understanding of a compressed public key is limited. Is there a way to get the `pub_key` from `compressed_pub_key`?

Comment: Yes, as I realized by myself, the compressed public key obtained by `ecdsa_recover` is not identical with the `AccountId`, but it should be possible to derive it by hashing or by invoking the corresponding function from the `the_compatibility` crate. I updated my answer above accordingly.

Comment: When I do `AccountId::from(pub_key)` it's throwing an error saying `the trait From<ink_env::types::AccountId> is not implemented for ink_env::AccountId`

Comment: Can you try the 4 steps outlined above?

Comment: I've pushed my code here: https://github.com/kanishkatn/verify_signature/blob/master/lib.rs . There is a compilation error at line 28.

Comment: It doesn't work without that either since the type of `AccountId` returned from `ecdsa_key.to_default_account_id()` and `Self::env().caller()` are different.

Comment: Indeed, `to_default_account_id()` already returns an `AccountId` struct, you don't need `AccountId::from`. The new error is due to different versions of your crates, since you are obtaining `eth_compatibility` from GitHub. Just remove the `git = ...` from your `Cargo.toml` for `eth_compatibility`

Answer (score 4):

You could get the Public key (hex) using the inspect command of subkey -->
Take a look at this link:
[enter link description here](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/tools/subkey/)

If you already have it (for example `0xd6a3105d6768e956e9e5d41050ac29843f98561410d3a47f9dd5b3b227ab8746`), add `hex-literal = "0.3.4"` in your Cargo.toml, and then in your ink contract, your account Id will be:

```
AccountId = hex_literal::hex!["d6a3105d6768e956e9e5d41050ac29843f98561410d3a47f9dd5b3b227ab8746"].into();
```

Comment: Let me clarify, I'm getting the compressed public key back from `ink_env::ecdsa_recover` and I wanna use that to compare it to an `AccountId` in the ink contract. `hex_literal::hex!` only works on string literals.

Comment: I believe it's not possible to do that with subkey inspect. This is what it says in it's --help : `Gets a public key and a SS58 address from the provided Secret URI`.

Comment: Got it! Sorry, I tried...